# Sending on behalf of users with Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Sometimes it's necessary to send an email with the reply-to address of another user. For example, if a LinkedIn user sends a connection of theirs a LinkedIn message, it makes sense to send that email from the user that sent the message, so that clicking 'reply' actually replies to the person who sent the message.

Is there a way to do this with Amazon SES?

Comment: did you try playing with headers? You should be able to specify a different reply-to address on each emali.

Comment: Predictaby, Microsoft hasn't heard about `Reply-To:` and will ignore it.

Comment: Hahaaa! That's hilarious @tripleee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `ReplyToAddresses` parameter in `$ses->sendEmail()` ([documentation PHP V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail), assuming other languages and versions will have similar structure, search for it)

```
$sesClient->sendEmail([
    'Source' => 'sender@mail.ru',
    'Destination' => 'dummy@clie.nt',
    'Message' => [
        'Subject' => [
            'Data' => 'Spammer attack',
        ],
        'Body' => [
            'Html' => [
                'Data' => 'Le Attacke!',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'ReplyToAddresses' => [
        'reply@ema.il',
        'sender@mail.ru',
        'dummy@clie.nt',
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Strange this was failing at first for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Costa Maybe you set `ReplyToAddresses` to string?

Comment: I use node.js, for my driver it is optionally a driver or a string, and it's called 'replyTo'. It's working right now with just a string.